# Post Telegram message with multiple external photos using WTelegramClient

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

Post telegram message with single external photo:

```
var im = new InputMediaPhotoExternal();
im.url = a.Photo;
await client.SendMessageAsync(target, null, im);
```

Is it possible to post message with multiple external photos using `WTelegramClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigation, I found out Telegram doesn't normally accept external URLs in grouped albums.

However I have now added in [WTelegramClient](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient) *(version 2.0.0 or more recent)* a new helper method `SendAlbumAsync` that simplify the sending of grouped media (albums) and that also supports external photo/documents:

```cs
InputPeer target = InputPeer.Self;
var inputMedias = new InputMedia[]
{
    new InputMediaPhotoExternal() { url = "https://picsum.photos/200/200.jpg" },
    new InputMediaPhotoExternal() { url = "https://picsum.photos/310/200.jpg" },
};
await client.SendAlbumAsync(target, inputMedias, "caption");
```

*(external URLs are downloaded automatically by WTelegramClient using HttpClient, and uploaded to Telegram)*

Comment: Please update NuGet package to 1.9.5. Great library, ty!

Comment: @AsValeO NuGet package 2.0.0 was just released